# Regex find all closing html tags, all opening separately

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function performing filtering on strings. I currently have the filter stripping out all html tags.

```
return String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
```

I've realized that I actually need to perform two operations:
First, to replace all closing tags with `<br>` and then a second operation to remove all opening tags.

I'm not too familiar with regEx. How could I specify `/<[^>]+>/gm` to be only opening or closing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454.

Comment: Just so you know, parsing HTML in a foolproof manner is more complicated than a regex can handle.  Some simple things can be done on straightforward HTML, but it only takes a few characters in a tag attribute or in an embedded script to throw everything off.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double replace function.

```
> var str = "<h1>foo bar</h1>"
undefined
> str.replace(/<\w[^>]*>/, "").replace(/<\/[^>]+>/, "<br>")
'foo bar<br>'
```

OR

Use single replace function which uses a capturing group based regex.

```
> var str = "<h1>foo bar</h1>"
> str.replace(/<(\w+\b)[^>]*>([^<>]*)<\/\1>/, '$2<br>')
'foo bar<br>'
```

We must back-reference  (`\1`) to the first capturing group instead of second because the 1st itself contain the tag-name.

Comment: Isn't it `\2` instead of `$2` for the second capturing group?

Comment: we must refer to the first capturing group instead of second because the 1st itself contain the tag-name.

Comment: Maybe I'm making a mistake in what I'm looking at. What does the `$2` in `'$2<br>'` mean?

Comment: `$2` refers to the characters which exists in-between the openening and closing tag.

Comment: This will fail on basic valid HTML syntax such as `< div>`.

Comment: How to get all these opening and closing html tags to an array?